# Arrow up and down does not work any more in Perl debugger and CPAN client

Tags: perl, debugging, cpan, arrow-keys, perl5.12

I used to use Active Perl on my Mac OS X (v 10.7.5) and then I switched to the one provided via mac ports (v 5.12.4).

Now when I run the CPAN client or the perl debugger, I cannot access the history using ArrowUp and ArrowDown, what is shown at the prompt is `^[[A` and `^[[B` respectively.

At least on the debugger the history works, I can access past commands via !*num*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default the only `Term::ReadLine` handler you get is `Term::ReadLine::Perl` which is quite simple and doesn't understand things like arrow keys. You probably want to install `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have enough points, but I surely will!

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, `cpanm Term::ReadLine::Gnu` failed initially. Had to run `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev` first.

Comment: This worked for me in OS X 10.9.5 with a perlbrewed 5.18.4.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ***avoid*** installing additional **OS** libraries (or need to because you don't have root/sudo) you can just **use CPAN** (as opposed to doing a *system* install with rpm or apt) to grab one of these two Perl implementations of Readline:

- [Term::ReadLine::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Perl/) (Perl implementation of Readline libraries)
- [Term::Readline::Zoid](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Zoid/) (*Pure* Perl implementation of Readline libraries)

It's especially handy if you already have your own local Perl install (eg, using Perlbrew) where it won't want to use any system-installed modules.

Comment: Uh? I you want to avoid installing additional libraries, you need to install the following additional libraries?

Comment: @fishinear The difference is _where_ they are installed, at the OS level, or just within the confines of Perl.  You don't really need an rpm or deb for it.  I've edited my answer to try to clarify the difference.

Comment: This helped me. `cpan -f Term::ReadLine::Perl` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the answers from LeoNerd and Hakon :-
On CentOS 7 I had to run

```
sudo yum install perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu
```

to install the module. Now the arrow keys work in perl -d

Answer (score 2):

This is what helped me on Debian stretch

```
apt install libterm-readline-gnu-perl
```

Answer (score 1):

For "git for Windows" you can do the following:

From

[Ilya Zakharevich's package Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303](https://metacpan.org/release/Term-ReadLine-Perl)

download the file

```
Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303.tar.gz
```

extract it with

```
tar xvzf ../Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303.tar.gz
```

Two files

```
Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303/ReadLine/Perl.pm
Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303/ReadLine/readline.pm
```

have to be copied typically with admin rights into the directory

```
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/share/perl5/site_perl/Term/ReadLine/
```

resulting in the two files

```
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/share/perl5/site_perl/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm and
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/share/perl5/site_perl/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm
```

Afterwards you can use the cursor keys inside the perl debugger, for instance
inside a "perl -de 0" session.

In the 64 bit git for Windows SDK, you usually have to copy the two files into directory

```
C:/git-sdk-64/usr/share/perl5/site_perl/Term/ReadLine
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was changing the term of my 'Terminal' window to vt100 under the Preferences > Advanced

Comment: This did not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do to get it working with Cygwin Perl

Install the following Cygwin packages:

```
libncurses-devel
libreadline-devel
```

Then install the `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` module from CPAN