# Arrow keys in perl debugger works in one PuTTy session but not on another

Tags: perl, putty

I have one saved session in PuTTy (connecting to a RHEL box) where `perl -d` and the arrow keys works very nice.

I have the same PuTTy version, and using session1, I cloned to connect to a different but similar RHEL box and the arrows does not work?

According to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783334/arrow-up-and-down-does-not-work-any-more-in-perl-debugger-and-cpan-client), session1 should have also not been working as I do not have `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` on that first box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`, other modules may fill the same need. I use `Term::ReadLine::Perl`. You may have that module (or another equivalent) installed on the first box but not on the second.

The linked answer claims that `Term::ReadLine::Perl` does not have arrow-key support, which may have been true at one time, but arrow keys work fine for me.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be right, though I had an error even on the first box with `perl -MTerm::ReadLine::Perl` throwing an error... but checking on the 2nd box the error certainly says `Can't locate Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm in @INC ....` Lemme try to install on the 2nd box. Thanks @DanLowe

Comment: YES! I installed it and it works, only I'm getting an error if I just `perl -MTerm::ReadLine::Perl` getting `Can't locate object method "Features" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at ...` still `perl -d` works. I wonder what I'm missing from the **Features** ?

Comment: It's because `Term::ReadLine::Stub` is not installed. Reading over the code in `Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm` it seems like it tries to use 3 parent classes if they are installed, but if not it just keeps going. This is some older hard-to-read code so I'm not sure how it works, but it seems to work fine without that Stub module... *shrug* I don't have `Term::ReadLine::Stub` installed either, and it works fine.